# Is this 2-complex a $K(\pi,1)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider $CW$-complex $X$ obtained from $S^1\vee S^1$ by glueing two $2$-cells by the loops $a^5b^{-3}$ and $b^3(ab)^{-2}$. As we can see in Hatcher (p. 142), abelianisation of $\pi_1(X)$ is trivial, so we have $\widetilde H_i(X)=0$ for all $i$. And if $\pi_2(X)=0$, we have that $X$ is $K(\pi,1)$.

My question is: *how can one compute* $\pi_2(X)$? Computing homotopy groups is hard, what methods may i use?

Comment: WHY $\pi_2=0$ IMPLIES $X$ is $K(\pi,1)$ ?

Comment: @Anubhav.K, 'cause universal covering of $X$ is 2-dimensional without $\pi_2$, so it's aspherical

Comment: not true.  see my answer below(its an answer because I couldnt fit it into a comment0

Comment: @HariRau-Murthy mayby, in your example $X$ is not $2$-dimensional $CW$-complex? in such case we really have $X=K(\pi,1)$ because of $\widetilde X$ has the same homology as a point

Comment: Sorry for being thick :(.  Yeah.  The $X$ in your example, is a 2-dimensional CW complex so $\pi_i(X)$ is automatically 0 for $i\geq 3$.  So $\pi_2(X)=0 \Rightarrow X$ is aspherical.

Comment: I somehow thought, for reasons that are no longer clear, that you had thought that this space being acyclic+(another condition) would imply that $X$ is an eilenberg maclane space.  But obviously you would never do that. I'll leave my answer up though, because I still like my own example :).

Comment: relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84422/finite-dimensional-eilenberg-maclane-spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\pi_2(X)=\mathbb Z^{119}$, is is obvious by considering Euler characteristic.

Denote universal cover of $X$ by $\widetilde X$. In Hatcher we see (and i don't know how to prove it) that $\pi_1(X)$ has order $120$. So $\widetilde X$ has 120 $0$-cells, 240 $1$-cells, and 240 $2$-cells; therefore $\chi(\widetilde X)=120$.

We know that $H_0(\widetilde X)=\mathbb Z$, $H_1(\widetilde X)=0$ and $H_2(\widetilde X)$ has no torsion. So $H_2(\widetilde X)=\pi_2(\widetilde X)=\pi_2(X)=\mathbb Z^{119}$.

Comment: this is a better solution

Answer (score 3):

Letting $\widetilde X$ be the universal cover of $X$ we have
$$\pi_2(X) \approx \pi_2(\widetilde X) \approx H_2(\widetilde X,\mathbb{Z})
$$
The first isomorphism comes from the long exact sequence of homotopy groups of a fibration, using discreteness of the fiber of the universal covering map. The second isomorphism comes from the Hurewicz theorem, using simple connectivity of $\widetilde X$.

Comment: but why $H_2(\hat{X} , \mathbb Z)=0$ ?? here OP asked whether $X$ is $KG,1)$ or not?? How can we conclude anything about $H_2(\hat{X} , \mathbb Z)$

Comment: dear ee Mosher, here you don't answer my question, but i already can do it (after weeks of trying). maybe, equality that i think out is actually what you mean?

Comment: This an answer to the question of how to compute $\pi_2(X)$ in this situation. The general answer is, calculate $H_2(\widetilde X, \mathbb{Z})$. Whether this is helpful, will depend on your ability to work constructively in $\widetilde X$, as in the other answer @Anubhav.K

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
The statement $\pi_2(X)=0$ would imply that $X$ is a $K(\pi,1)$, is not true.  I will construct for you now an acyclic space,(the space $X$ below) with $\pi_2=0$, that is not an eilenberg maclane space.

Let $2I$ be the $\Z/2$ extension of the icosahedral group, $I$, given by the preimage of $I$ under $spin(3) \to SO(3)$(FYI spin(3) is the connected double cover of $SO(3)$).  Since $I$ is perfect,i.e. $H_1(I)=0$,  the hoschild-serre spectral sequence of this extension implies that $H_1(2I)$ is perfect.  Therefore by the Quillen plus construction there is a space with $X$ with $\tilde H_*(X)=0$, and $\pi_1(X)=2I$.  Since $2I$ is not an acyclic group, $K(2I,1) \neq X$ in the homotopy category.    But if $X$ were an eilenberg maclane space it would have to be $K(2I,1)$.  Therefore $X$ is not an eilenberg maclane space. Furthermore, since $\pi_2(\text{quillen plus construction on } A_5)=\Z/2$, $\pi_2(X)=0$.