# What is the total space of the universal bundle over $B\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

> What is the total space of the universal bundle over $B\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. what is $E\mathbb{Q}$ for $B\mathbb{Q}=E\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Q}$ where $B\mathbb{Q}$ is the classifying space?

*Thoughts/Attempt*: $B\mathbb{Q}=E\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Q}$ and $B\mathbb{Q}=K(
\mathbb{Q},1)$ so $E\mathbb{Q}=K(
\mathbb{Q},1)\rtimes\mathbb{Q}$. Now we just need $K(\mathbb{Q},1).$ The classifying space of $\mathbb{Z}$ is a canonical example, but I haven't seen it for $\mathbb{Q}$.

Thanks in advance! I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is a certain filtered colimit of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$, so you can describe $B\mathbb{Q}$ as a certain filtered colimit of circles. It's known as the "rational circle."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: a filtered colimit copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, you mean? Or have I misunderstood? (To the OP: the construction Qiaochu describes is also explained in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/84467/73817)

Comment: Whoops, yeah, that.

Comment: Could you write this as an answer? @QiaochuYuan

Comment: @Jake, true, but since $\Omega \mathbb{Q}\simeq\ast$ regardless of its topology, the resulting classifying space $B\mathbb{Q}$ will be a $K(\mathbb{Q},1)$ anyway.